# How close am I to the true minimum?

Tags: inference, extreme-value, measurement-error

This might be a trivial question but my statistics knowledge very is rudimentary:

I'm trying to measure the amount of clock cycles that my computer needs to execute a certain function. The number of cycles can very significantly from one measurement to the next because of variable overhead.

I believe that the amount of clock cycles obtained with each measurement depends on three components:

- A fixed minimum number of cycles needed to execute the function itself ($n_f$).
- The minimum number of overhead cycles that will always occur, even in the most ideal circumstances ($n_{o1}$).
- Additional variable overhead cycles that vary strongly from measurement to measurement ($n_{o2}$).

Since there's no good method for distinguishing $n_f$ and $n_{o1}$, I would like to estimate their sum $n_f + n_{o1}$. I do this by simply taking the minimum of several thousand measurements.

Now my question is how I can quantify how good (i.e. how close to the actual value $n_f + n_{o1}$) this estimate is. My measurements look like this:

[image]

The five lowest occurring cycles counts are (they are all even for technical reasons):

- 48 (1 times)
- 50 (10446 times)
- 52 (119004 times)
- 54 (388845 times)
- 55 (288816 times)

So 48 would be my best guess here. However, since this value occurs only once it seems to me that this method might not be very robust and if I ran the same experiment many times (which is unfortunately not feasible) I might see a different minimum each time. Is there some standard way of expressing this uncertainty?

Comment: With your enormous number of replications, you must be very close --- you got 48 in one out of about a half million replicates, for practical purposes I would treat that as close to sure ...